# How to calculate the sum of all columns and rows of a matrix efficiently in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I would like to calculate the sum of all columns and the sum of all rows of a matrix in CUDA. One way of doing that is to use the `SGEMV` subroutine from BLAS, multiplying the matrix by a vector of 1s.

However, this leads to **two** scans of the matrix, assuming it is much bigger than the L1 cache: one for rows and another for columns. Additionally, I plan to further modify the code for other operators, and so this is why I am writing my own kernel.

My approach so far has been to break the matrix into submatrices of size `32 x 32`. Each thread block loads such a submatrix into shared memory, calculates the sums of rows and colums of the submatrix, and adds them atomically to the appropriate output (`row` and `col` below). This way, the matrix data only needs to be read from VRAM once.

For simplicity, the code assumes that the matrix is `n x n`, `n % 32 == 0` and the thread block is `32 x 32`

```
__global__ void sum_cols_and_rows(size_t n, const float* matrix, float* col, float* row)
{   
    __shared__ float sh[32][32];

    size_t x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    size_t y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    float sum = matrix[x + n * y];
    sh[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = sum;

    for(unsigned w = 16; w >= 1; w /= 2)
        sum += __shfl_down(sum, w);
    const size_t laneID = threadIdx.x & 0x1f; // 32-1
    if(laneID == 0)
        atomicAdd(row + y, sum);
    __syncthreads();

    sum = sh[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x]; // swapped indexes
    for(unsigned w = 16; w >= 1; w /= 2)
        sum += __shfl_down(sum, w);
    if(laneID == 0)
        atomicAdd(col + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.y, sum);
}

// launch :
sum_cols_and_rows<<<dim3(n/32, n/32), dim3(32, 32), 32*32*sizeof(float)>>>(n, matrix, col, row);
```

However, the performance is rather disappointing. I am seeing about 20% of the theoretical 224GB/s memory bandwidth on GTX 980, even on large matrices, *e.g.* 16384x16384.

Is there any way to make this approach the theoretical bandwidth limit?

Comment: You can try `sh[32][33];` - this might help with shared memory bank conflicts. Other than that, I'm not sure you benefit from having N^2 threads per NxN block, you can try with N (perhaps with bigger N), without need for shared memory at all.

Comment: @zch sh[32][33] gave me a 50% speed-up, although I'm still at 30% of the theoretical limit. Thanks! I think I need shared memory to send data from thread (x,y) to thread (y, x) in a block, and avoid re-reading that value from VRAM.

Comment: Not really. What I was suggesting was having N threads per block and having each thread calculating one vertical sum. Similar to: `for(i 0..N-1) { float v = matrix[i][threadIdx]; vertical += v; horizontalShuffle(v); if(threadIdx==0) AtomicAdd(v); } AtomicAdd(vertical)`.

Comment: Or you can keep shared memory and do `for(i 0..N-1) { float v = matrix[i][threadIdx]; vertical += v; sh[i][threadIdx] = v; } AtomicAdd(vertical); sync(); for(i 0..N-1) { horizontal += sh[threadIdx][i]; }; AtomicAdd(horizontal);` without any shuffles. For big enough matrices it might be most efficient.

Comment: @zch Your "no shared memory" suggestion got me to 71% bandwidth, which is close to what I see with "1D reduce" from CUDA samples, so this is probably about as good as it gets. **Thanks!** (By the way: at first I thought you were talking about column-major (FORTRAN) layout, which performed poorly -- non-coalesced access, I'm guessing)

Comment: @zch So, the problem with my original code, after I fixed the bank conflicts was too many threads or bytes of shared memory per block, leading to too few blocks being able to run at the same time, limiting the number of SMs working at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution every NxN block of the matrix is being processed by separate NxN block of threads. In effect every individual thread does very little work, so overhead dominates actual computation. You could improve it by having thread blocks process more than one matrix block.

But there is a simpler solution, using only N threads per matrix block, where one threads sums the whole column.

Implementation would be similar to this:

```
__global__ void sum_cols_and_rows(size_t n, const float* matrix, float* col, float* row)
{   
    size_t laneID = threadIdx.x & 31;

    size_t x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    size_t y = N_ITERATIONS * blockIdx.y;

    size_t idx = y * n + x;

    float vertical = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++) {
        float v = matrix[idx];
        vertical += v;
        for(unsigned w = 16; w >= 1; w /= 2)
            v += __shfl_down(v, w);
        if(laneID == 0)
            atomicAdd(&row[y], v);
        y++;
        idx += n;
    }

    atomicAdd(&col[x], vertical);
}
```

Tunable parameters here are number of warps per thread group and number of rows in each matrix block (`N_ITERATIONS`). Bigger values might decrease overhead, at the cost of parallelism.

Another idea to experiment with is [vectorized loading](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-increase-performance-with-vectorized-memory-access/) - one of:

```
float2 v2 = reinterpret_cast<float2*>(matrix)[idx];
float v = v2.x + v2.y;

float4 v4 = reinterpret_cast<float4*>(matrix)[idx];
float v = (v4.x + v4.y) + (v4.z + v4.w);
```